# xcode 4.6 command line tools will not install

Tags: xcode

I'm running **OSX 10.7.5** on my **MacBook Pro**.I want to run `ImageMagick` so I installed `XCODE V 4.6.3` (because when I tried to install ImageMagick I got a message that the XCODE version 3.2.5 was too old)

After installing the newer XCODE, I tried once again to install ImageMagick and I get

```
Warning: The Xcode Command Line Tools don't appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build.
```

Trying to install the command line tools via `"preferences" in XCODE`, I get:

```
The package “BluetoothSDK.pkg” is untrusted.
```

The only option is to select OK and the tools are not installed.

I tried installing a few other `simulators` and get similar messages although not always regarding bluetooth.

What is the trick to doing this?

Comment: Consider using `homebrew` to install ImageMagick on OSX. It is much easier that way. Ask if you don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
xcode-select --install
```

from the command line, which should trigger the Command Line Tools installer.

Comment: I have tried the xcode-select --install suggestion already. Here is the result:

Comment: new-host:/ smiller85715$ xcode-select --install
Usage: xcode-select -print-path
   or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
   or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
   -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
   -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
   -version                        Prints xcode-select version information
new-host:/ smiller85715$

Comment: I'll try the "homebrew" approach but I don't know how to use it.